# How to have tabs of matching height with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap tabs to display some content. Each of my tabs is almost the same height, but not exactly so when you switch tabs, there is a slight movement of the next component.

Is it possible to make each tab panel the height of the maximum height ?

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ommnft3e/
I'd like the `<hr>` to not move when I switch tabs. Is that possible ?

Thanks

Comment: i cant find a bit different on that

Comment: They both look the same to me as well.

Comment: can you please post any pic showing difference as we can't see any difference?

Comment: check these for inspiration - sounds like you want to make each div the same height, regardless of how much content there is - The <hr> moves because there's one line of content in the first tab, and a few lines in the second... If you work out which tab has the most height, you can set all tabs to be that height.. see this as an example: http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/ or http://www.broken-links.com/2009/01/20/very-quick-equal-height-columns-in-jquery/ or http://www.cssnewbie.com/equal-height-columns-with-jquery/

Comment: @Abdulla The first panel is one line of text long while the second panel is four lines long. When you change tabs (click on tab headers), the hr line move up and down. I want both panels to have matching height as Damien said. I'll try with Javascript but I hoped to avoid javascript.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Override the bootstrap css and Use visibility hidden

```
.tab-content>.tab-pane{
    display:block;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.tab-content>.active{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

see the fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/devjit/ommnft3e/5/

In that case I think you will have to use javascript to determine the max height. check this fiddle .. https://jsfiddle.net/devjit/ommnft3e/8/

Comment: In that case, the hr does not move, but now the second tab has an empty line at the beginning. If you had a third tab, it has 5 empty lines at the beginning which is not what I want.

Comment: sorry for the previous answer, couldn't see the problem with the visibility hidden approach.. I think you will have to use javascript to attain this.

Comment: I used JS at the end to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: **NOTE** for future readers: This answer has 10 upvotes but doesn't actually work!

Comment: Works greatly for me on 2 tabs. I'm using bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this little script that manages the tab pane heights and adjust it to make them all the same height.

```
function tabHeightManager() {

this.margin = 0;
this.selcheck = '';
this.selmod = '';
this.running = false;

}

tabHeightManager.prototype.bind = function( _selcheck, _selmod, _margin ) {

if (typeof(_selcheck) === 'undefined')
    return false;
else
    this.selcheck = _selcheck;

if (typeof(_selmod) === 'undefined')
    return false;
else
    this.selmod = _selmod;

(typeof(_margin) === 'undefined') ? this.margin = 0 : this.margin = _margin;

var self = this;
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    setTimeout( function() { self.recalc() }, 200 );
})

self.recalc();
}

tabHeightManager.prototype.recalc = function() {
if(this.running)
    return false;

this.running = true;

var max = 0;
$(this.selcheck).each(function () {
    if (max < $(this).outerHeight(true))
        max = $(this).outerHeight(true);
});

max += this.margin;
$(this.selmod).css({'height': max});

this.running = false;
}
```

Just create the bootstrap tabs and after that call

```
    var tabMan = new tabHeightManager();
    tabMan.bind('.tab-pane','.tab-content',15);
```

It's quite crap but I arranged it in a hurry, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of data...
In Tab A it has only one row. So Scroll bar not visible When you click on Tab B it has more than one row. So it will display scroll bar. Bcoz of that you feel like height changes.
Tab height is depends on Tab Content..

```
<div class="tab-content">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab_0_0">
                       <p>Test</p>
                        <p>Test</p>
                        <p>Test</p>
                        <p>Test</p>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab_0_4">
                        <p>Test</p>
                        <p>Test</p>
                        <p>Test</p>
                        <p>Test</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**[Check this Tab](https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/ommnft3e/4/)**

**OR**

Use fixed height for both Tab and add scroll bar...

Comment: I know that the content is different and that this cause the problem, but I don't want to change the content.

Comment: @Devjit except that the height is now cumulative, each panel has empty space at its beginning.

Comment: Then go for second method..where you need to set the tab height and  inline scroll bar...